# How to stub a method in Mockito whose name is not known until runtime?

Tags: java, reflection, mocking, mockito

I'd like to test that every method with a known prefix in a specific class is called during a particular test.

I can't work out a way to use mockito to stub out a method or how to verify that method has been called when the method name is not known until runtime.

The code below shows how I can get the methods I'd like to stub:

```
Method[] methodArr = customValidation.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
loop: for (Method method : methodArr) {
    if (method.getName().startsWith("validate")) {
        // then stub out this method and check whether it gets called
        // after we run some code
    }
}
```

The question is, how can I stub them without know the method names until runtime?

Has anyone done anything like this before or have a good idea of how it can be done?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not appear to be possible as of now. There is an [unresolved enhancement request](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/issues/detail?id=103)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who's interested, the solution I used was to use regular mocking to stub my methods:

```
UserBeanValidation userBeanValidation = Mockito.mock(UserBeanValidation.class);
Mockito.when(userBeanValidation.validateUserId(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(validationError);
```

I verified they were called once and incremented a count whenever one of the stubbed methods was executed. This count could be compared with a count of methods with a specific prefix to ensure all expected methods were called:

```
int totalMethodCount= 0;
Method[] methodArr = customValidation.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
loop: for (Method method : methodArr) {

    if (method.getName().startsWith("validate")) {
        totalMethodCount++;
    }
}

Assert.assertEquals(totalMethodCount, calledMethodCount);
```

This way I can be sure that all my methods are called... now to find out if they do what they're supposed to.